# c# - Get AssemblyTitle

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I know the .NET Core replacement for `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` is `typeof(MyType).GetTypeInfo().Assembly`, but what about the replacement for

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AssemblyTitleAttribute), false)
```

I have tried appending the last bit of the code after assembly for the first solution mentioned like so:

```
typeof(VersionInfo).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AssemblyTitleAttribute));
```

but it gives me a "Can't implicitly convert to object[] message.

**UPDATE:**
Yes, as comments below indicate, I believe it is linked to the output type.

Here is the code snippet, and I am just trying to change it to be compatible with .Net Core:

```cs
public class VersionInfo 
{
    public static string AssemlyTitle 
    {
        get 
        {
            object[] attributes = Assembly
                .GetExecutingAssembly()
                .GetCustomAttributes(typeof (AssemblyTitleAttribute), false);
          // More code follows
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried changing this to use `CustomAttributeExtensions.GetCustomAttributes()` but I don't know how to implement the same code as above. I still get mixed up about `MemberInfo` and `Type` and the like.

Any help is extremely appreciated!

Comment: Where do you get the error message? Is `VersionInfo` in the same assembly as the `AssemblyTitle` you're trying to read?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suspect that the issue is in code you have not shown: where you use the result of `GetCustomAttributes()`. That's because [`Assembly.GetCustomAttributes(Type, bool)` in .Net Framework returns `object[]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88d17d13(v=vs.110).aspx), while [`CustomAttributeExtensions.GetCustomAttributes(this Assembly, Type)` in .Net Core returns `IEnumerable<Attribute>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/api/system.reflection.customattributeextensions#System_Reflection_CustomAttributeExtensions_GetCustomAttributes_System_Reflection_Assembly_System_Type_).

So you need to modify your code accordingly. The simplest way would be to use `.ToArray<object>()`, but a better solution might be to change your code so that it can work with `IEnumerable<Attribute>`.

Comment: You have definitely shed some light on the situation. I have added more of the code I am working with in the hopes of getting some additional guidance.

Comment: @PirateJubber Added.

Answer (score 31):

Wouldn't this be the simplest?

```
string title = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyTitleAttribute>().Title;
```

Just say'in.

Comment: In some situations, one may consider substituting `GetEntryAssembly` instead of `GetExecutingAssembly`, such as when creating a progress dialog box in a class library that you want to have display the calling application's title.

Answer (score 9):

This works for me in .NET Core 1.0:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace SO_38487353
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var attributes = typeof(Program).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AssemblyTitleAttribute));
            var assemblyTitleAttribute = attributes.SingleOrDefault() as AssemblyTitleAttribute;

            Console.WriteLine(assemblyTitleAttribute?.Title);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

**AssemblyInfo.cs**

```
using System.Reflection;

[assembly: AssemblyTitle("My Assembly Title")]
```

**project.json**

```
{
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.0.0"
    },
    "System.Runtime": "4.1.0"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": { }
  }
}
```

Comment: I neglected to share the entire situation of what I was trying to do, but you are right, your solution does fix the error. Is there any way to rework it to work with object[]?

Answer (score 6):

This works for me:

```
public static string GetAppTitle()
{
    AssemblyTitleAttribute attributes = (AssemblyTitleAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), typeof(AssemblyTitleAttribute), false);

    return attributes?.Title;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what i use:

```
private string GetApplicationTitle => ((AssemblyTitleAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), typeof(AssemblyTitleAttribute), false))?.Title ?? "Unknown Title";
```