# How to set AssemblyTitleAttribute in NETCore1.1

Tags: .net, .net-core, .net-assembly, assembly-attributes

In .NETCore1.1, next code

```
typeof(Program).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetCustomAttributes().ToList()
```

returns list of custom assembly attributes and one of them is `AssemblyTitleAttribute`. By default this attribute value returns project name, but how can I set any other value?

Tried to add assembly information file `AssemblyInfo.cs` how it's described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38488566/524605), but getting error

> error CS0579: Duplicate 'System.Reflection.AssemblyTitleAttribute'
>   attribute

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right now properties could be defined in `.csproj` or using `AssemblyInfo.cs`, but only the one place could be used, otherwise "Duplicate" errors are generated.

If you want to use `AssemblyInfo.cs`, add the following into `.csproj` to avoid duplication errors:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
</PropertyGroup>
```

If you are interesting how does it work, look into [GenerateAssemblyInfo task](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/blob/master/src/Tasks/Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks/build/Microsoft.NET.GenerateAssemblyInfo.targets#L26).

---

Otherwise remove `AssemblyInfo.cs` and add the following into your `.csproj` file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <AssemblyTitle>My library</AssemblyTitle>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Great! Thanks much! <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo> is what I need